# Pass variadic std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-argument-deduction

I have a function that accepts a callback. It should work with function ptrs, lambdas (stateless & with state), etc. I could just do the following:

```
template<typename t_func>
void add_command(const std::string& name, t_func func)
```

The problem is I need to work with the argument types of func. So I did this:

```
template<typename... t_args>
void add_command(const std::string& name, const std::function<void(t_args...)>& args)
```

This creates the following error: `no matching function for call to`...

`note: template argument deduction/substitution failed`

Is there any way to pass a generic function type while still having access to it's arguments? I know of `std::result_of`, is there a similar `std::arguments_of`?

Comment: You might create function traits as `argument_of`, but you are limited: you no longer accept generic lambda and generic functor, or functor with overloads.

Comment: All commands in your system must have the same known signatute. If you think you need to support arbitrary signatures, you haven't thought your design through.

Comment: How are you going to write code that calls `func`?

Comment: It's a command processor. I parse a string with whitespace seperated arguments which are casted accordingly to fit the functions signature.

Comment: I would suggest `template<typename... args, typename t_func>
void add_command(const std::string& name, t_func func)` and then you just have to specify the argument types as template parameters when you call the function.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing right now. I thought there's a more convenient way though

Comment: @n.m. Not exactly. I created a wrapper function which casts strings to the desired arguments. But for that I need to know which arguments I need to cast to.

Comment: "created a wrapper function which casts strings to the desired arguments" It isn't quite clear what you have, what is working, and what isn't. Please show relevant information in the question itself.

Comment: @n.m. The only problem is std::function<void(t_args...)>. If I replace it with void(*)(t_args...) everything works fine. The problem is I'd like to support capturing lambdas. I don't see how explaining completely unrelated code would help making the question more understandable.

Comment: You are making yourself less clear with each new comment. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Read the last sentence of my question again and forget what I might wanna do with the callback. It's completely unrelated.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use `std::function<void(t_args...)` in a place that needs something else entirely, but it's hard to tell what it is exactly without knowing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

`std::function` is a type erasure template.  Type deduction is the opposite (almost the inverse) of type erasure.

Type deducing a type erasure template is code smell.  And it rarely works.

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) there is a deduction guide, so you can do:

```
template<typename... t_args>
void add_command(const std::string& name, const std::function<void(t_args...)>& args)        
void add_command(const std::string& name, t_func const& func) {
  std::function f = func;
  add_command(name, f);
}
```

it is imperfect, but a perfect solution isn't possible.

The deduction guides [look like](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/deduction_guides):

```
template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
function(R(*)(ArgTypes...)) -> function<R(ArgTypes...)>;
template<class F>
function(F) -> function</*see below*/>;
```

where it extracts the signature of the `function` via examining `&F::operator()`.  This can fail with overloads or templates.  And naturally this doesn't work with function names that are overloaded.

You can replicate this in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) with a function traits class:

```
template<class X>
struct function_traits:function_traits<decltype(&X::operator())> {};
#define MEM_FUN_HELPER2(...) \
  template<class R, class T, class...Args> \
  struct function_traits<R(T::*)(Args...) __VA_ARGS__>:function_traits<R(Args...)>{}; \
  template<class R, class T, class...Args> \
  struct function_traits<R(T::*)(Args..., ...) __VA_ARGS__>:function_traits<R(Args..., ...)>{}; \
  template<class R, class T, class...Args> \
  struct function_traits<R(T::*)(Args...) __VA_ARGS__ noexcept>:function_traits<R(Args...) noexcept>{}; \
  template<class R, class T, class...Args> \
  struct function_traits<R(T::*)(Args..., ...) __VA_ARGS__  noexcept>:function_traits<R(Args..., ...) noexcept>{}
#define MEM_FUN_HELPER1(...) \
  MEM_FUN_HELPER2(__VA_ARGS__); \
  MEM_FUN_HELPER2(__VA_ARGS__ &); \
  MEM_FUN_HELPER2(__VA_ARGS__ &&)
#define MEM_FUN_HELPER0(...) \
  MEM_FUN_HELPER1(__VA_ARGS__); \
  MEM_FUN_HELPER1(const __VA_ARGS__)
#define MEM_FUN_HELPER() \
  MEM_FUN_HELPER0(); \
  MEM_FUN_HELPER0(volatile)

MEM_FUN_HELPER();

template<class R, class...Args>
struct function_traits<R(*)(Args...)>:function_traits<R(Args...)>{};
template<class R, class...Args>
struct function_traits<R(*)(Args..., ...)>:function_traits<R(Args..., ...)>{};
template<class R, class...Args>
struct function_traits<R(*)(Args...) noexcept>:function_traits<R(Args...) noexcept>{};
template<class R, class...Args>
struct function_traits<R(*)(Args..., ...) noexcept>:function_traits<R(Args..., ...) noexcept>{};
template<class R, class...Args>
struct function_traits<R(Args...) noexcept> : function_traits<R(Args...)> {
  enum {is_noexcept=true};
};
template<class R, class...Args>
struct function_traits<R(Args..., ...) noexcept> : function_traits<R(Args..., ...)> {
  enum {is_noexcept=true};
};
template<class R, class...Args>
struct function_traits<R(Args...)> {
  template<template<class...>class Z>
  using transcribe=Z<R(Args...)>;
  using std_function = transcribe<std::function>;
  using result_type = R;
  using arg_tuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
  enum{is_noexcept=false};
};
template<class R, class...Args>
struct function_traits<R(Args..., ...)> {
  template<template<class...>class Z>
  using transcribe=Z<R(Args..., ...)>;
  using std_function = transcribe<std::function>;
  using result_type = R;
  // doesn't really work, but what ya gonna do:
  using arg_tuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
  enum{is_noexcept=false};
};
```

which is pretty crazy; `MEM_FUN_HELPER();` expands into 48 template specializations.  3 ref qualifiers (`&`, `&&` and nothing), then 4 other things (`const`, `volatile`, `noexcept` and `...` C-style varargs) that have to be handled "manually".

In any case, once you have that, you can do:

```
template<typename... t_args>
void add_command(const std::string& name, const std::function<void(t_args...)>& args)        
template<class t_func>
void add_command(const std::string& name, t_func const& func) {
  typename function_traits<t_func>::std_function f = func;
  add_command(name, f);
}
```

in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).  This (roughly and imperfectly) does the same as the [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) deduction guides.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48f289adfb9411a0).

Comment: Nice use of deduction guides.  As you said it isn't perfect but it will work for a number of cases. +1

Comment: And there are also the C-ellipsis cases (ala `printf`) for the traits  to double the boilerplate :-/

Comment: @Jarod42 Rewrote to be multiplicative